# How does DownGit downloads specific files or folders from GitHub (Under the hood)?

Tags: angular, github, download

I needed a solution to download specific file or folders from GitHub.
And, I come across DownGit, but I am interested to find out how it works under the hood.

I read the README.md of https://github.com/MinhasKamal/DownGit.
And, I am unable to get to the bottom of how this downloading works, the auther mentioned that every link will be converted to an URL prefix with 'https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url='.

However, I am missing how this logic is processed because this URL is generated.

Comment: - For downloading single file: 
Assume we provide this URL:   
https://github.com/worldpeacez0991/rnDrawerNavigation/blob/main/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties  
Becomes  
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/worldpeacez0991/rnDrawerNavigation/main/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: - For downloading folder with files: 
Assume we provide this URL:   
https://github.com/worldpeacez0991/SpringBoot_demo3B_REST_Service_Consumer/tree/main/src/main/java/com/example/restservice/consumer   
Becomes  
https://api.github.com/repos/worldpeacez0991/SpringBoot_demo3B_REST_Service_Consumer/contents/src/main/java/com/example/restservice/consumer?ref=main  
Which contains "download_urls" from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com'
Then DownGIT will wrap "download_urls" using method 'getFile' and zip all files into a single folder with the folder name 'wrapper.zip' to download for you.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not directly support cloning a specific folder from GitHub. Git operates at the repository level, not individual folders. However, there are some techniques you can use to clone a specific folder from a repository, such as sparse checkout or subtree.

Sparse checkout is a feature of Git that allows you to only checkout (download) a small portion of the repository instead of the entire thing. You can configure sparse checkout to only clone a specific folder. However, this requires some additional configuration and specific steps.

Create an empty repository on your computer using the git init command or use your existing repository.

Set up sparse checkout with the following command:

> git config core.sparseCheckout true

Create a .git/info/sparse-checkout file to specify the folders you want to clone:

> echo "path/to/directory" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout

Replace "path/to/directory" with the specific directory path you want to clone.

Add the URL of the repository from GitHub with the command:

> git remote add origin "URL"

Replace  with the URL of the repository from GitHub.

Download (clone) the repository using the command:

> git pull origin "branch"

Replace "branch" with the branch name you want to clone (typically master)